# How do I shift bit to Left after Hex conversion

Tags: c, arduino, bit-manipulation, arduino-c++

I'm converting input decimal value into hex and then I want to shift that value as below:

So if 51200 converts to hex: 0000 c800

Now I want to shift this value by 2 hex digits (8 bits): 00c8 00**00**

This is all because I'm trying to pass converted and shifted value into a microcontroller register which needs;

> 32 bits = 24+8 (24 bits integer part, 8 bits decimal places)

Here is my code where I'm getting the output as **0x0000C800**
but as I said I want now shift this value by eight bits to get 0x00C800**00**

```
void PrintHex32( uint32_t data) // prints 32-bit data in hex with leading zeroes
{
  char tmp[16];
  uint16_t LSB = data & 0xffff;
  uint16_t MSB = data >> 16;
  sprintf(tmp,"0x%.4X%.4X%", MSB, LSB);
  Serial.println(tmp);
  // Serial.println(temp2);
  Serial.println("************");
}
```

**EDIT: trial two as per David comment;**
 so I try to convert this before conversion but no luck! output: *0x00000000*

```
void PrintHex32( uint32_t data) // prints 32-bit data in hex with leading zeroes
{ 
  uint32_t data2 = data2<< 8;
  char tmp[16];
  uint16_t LSB = data2 & 0xffff;
  uint16_t MSB = data2 >> 16;
  sprintf(tmp,"0x%.4X%.4X%", MSB, LSB);
  Serial.println(tmp);

  // Serial.println(temp2);
  Serial.println("************");

}
```

Any help kindly appreciated as I'm burning out!

Comment: Understand, the "conversion" has no effect on the shift. (the bits are the same regardless how you look at it, hex/decimal/octal/binary) If you just want to shift left by the *byte* shown (NOT 2-bit), then `someunsigned = value << 8;` (e.g. `00c8 0000 = 0000 c800 << 8;`, which would be exactly the same as `51200 << 8;`)

Comment: You didn't do the shift you're looking for.

Comment: `"0x%.4X%.4X%"` is an invalid format (dandling `%`).  Suggest `"0x%04X%04X"`.

Comment: Your example shift output is the result of shifting 0x00C800 by 8 bits, not 2 bits.  Do you want the result you claim is correct, or the operation you think you want?  0x032000 is what you get from shifting 0x00C800 left by two bits.

Comment: @David C. Rankin  kindly check the new edit

Comment: Hi Jonathan my output is the right as that the value i want based on datasheet. i want 0x00C80000 after converting decimal 51200

Comment: Your new edit does `data2<< 8;` (`data2` is not initialized). I suspect you meant `data << 8;` Then confirm you want to shift ***before*** you take the high and low *words*. If so, then `uint32_t data2 = data << 8;`

Comment: @David C. Rankin Thanks Heaps!! it works!!

Comment: Glad it helped. Remember, when you look at a hex number, every one digit is a *nibble* (e.g. `0xf` 4-bits), every 2 digits is a *byte* (e.g. `0xff` 8-bits (one byte)), and so on. That is why, `data2 & 0xffff;` takes the low *word* (16-bits, 2-bytes) of `data2`.

Comment: Since you solved the problem yourself you can answer your own question in order to close it.